# AccessViolationException in SAPI is crashing my console

Tags: .net, text-to-speech, access-violation, sapi

I have a console application that has a function for creating files using a SAPI tts engine:

```vb
<HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions> Function SpeechFile(Text As String, Folder As String, Voice As String) As String
    Dim pth = Path.Combine(Folder, Text.GetHashCode & ".wav")
    If Not File.Exists(pth) Then
        Using synth = New SpeechSynthesizer
            Dim fmt = New Speech.AudioFormat.SpeechAudioFormatInfo(8000, Speech.AudioFormat.AudioBitsPerSample.Eight, Speech.AudioFormat.AudioChannel.Mono)
            synth.SetOutputToWaveFile(pth, fmt)
            synth.SelectVoice(Voice)
            Try
                synth.Speak(Text)
            Catch ex As Exception
                ex.Data.Add("Path", pth)
                ex.Data.Add("Text", Text)
                Throw ex 'i have no idea why this err isnt logged normally
            End Try
        End Using
    End If
    Return pth
End Function
```

The call to `Speak` fails intermittently with `AccessViolationException`. Even though I've added the `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions` attribute, and wrapped the call in a `Try...Catch`, this exception crashes the entire console application. I therefore have no way of logging the crash or handling/shutdown/restarting.

My first thought was that the engine was trying to create two files simultaneously, but this is not the case.

---

The relevant Windows logs:

> Faulting application name: MyConsole.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time
>   stamp: 0x56f8fd6e Faulting module name: Moses64.dll, version: 0.0.0.0,
>   time stamp: 0x510a6596 Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault offset:
>   0x00000000000d03a1 Faulting process id: 0x1c10 Faulting application
>   start time: 0x01d188d7da12cb52 Faulting application path: C:\Program
>   Files\MyConsole\MyConsole.exe Faulting module path:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Aharon\Hebrew Speech
>   Synthesizer\Ron\Moses64.dll Report Id:
>   0a70f320-f519-11e5-80c3-d05099606348 Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:
>
> Application: MyConsole.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException    at
>   System.Speech.Synthesis.TtsEngine.ITtsEngine.Speak(System.Speech.Synthesis.TtsEngine.SPEAKFLAGS,
>   System.Guid ByRef, IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr)    at
>   System.Speech.Internal.Synthesis.TtsProxySapi.Speak(System.Collections.Generic.List`1,
>   Byte[])    at
>   System.Speech.Internal.Synthesis.VoiceSynthesis.SpeakText(System.Speech.Internal.Synthesis.SpeakInfo,
>   System.Speech.Synthesis.Prompt,
>   System.Collections.Generic.List``1)
>   at System.Speech.Internal.Synthesis.VoiceSynthesis.ThreadProc()    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

---

How can I handle this exception, or better yet, prevent it from occurring?

Comment: Should be a bit obvious from the stack trace that this exception is thrown on a worker thread, not inside your SpeechFile() method.  So you cannot catch it.  You'll need to get your machine healthy again.  What that takes is impossible to guess, it requires an unmanaged debugger.  Avoid 3rd party voices, try another machine.

Comment: hi. thanks for your input. can you explain a bit more? if this is happening on a worker thread on an external process, how come my console is crashing? i dont mind that their engine crashes, but why is it bringing down my console with it? unfortunately i have no choice with the engine right now (due to licensing and management decisions etc). all i need is to gracefully ignore their bug. thanks!

Comment: Google "legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy".  Don't use it.

Comment: hi. i've read quite a bit about it. will removing it from my `app.config` actually enable the console to continue running when such an exception is thrown by the tts engine?

Answer (score -1):

in the end it was because i was missing the `legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy` in the `app.config`. (for some reason i had misplaced it into a wrong file)

once i've added it to my `app.config` the exception is getting handled very nicely

seems that `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions` by itself is not yet enough

thanks all for your help!